# Was the child in Isaiah 9:6 born during Isaiah's time? Were the victories in Isaiah 9:2-5 achieved militarily?

Tags: isaiah, referent-identification, historical-interpretation

If the child in Isaiah 9:6 was not born during Isaiah's time, who achieved the victories mentioned in Isaiah 9:2-5?

Were these victories achieved militarily?

> 2 The people walking in darkness have seen a great light; on those
> living in the land of the shadow of death, a light has dawned.
>
> 3 You have enlarged the nation and increased its joy. The people
> rejoice before You as they rejoice at harvest time, as men rejoice in
> dividing the plunder.
>
> 4 For as in the day of Midian You have shattered the yoke of their
> burden, the bar across their shoulders, and the rod of their
> oppressor.
>
> 5 For every trampling boot of battle and every garment rolled in blood
> will be burned as fuel for the fire.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the OP's question is "No".  There has never been an earthly Jewish king that achieved the victories listed in Isa 9:2-5.

However, we also know, via the inspired record of the NT writers that this passage is clearly messianic and applies to Jesus:

- Isa 9:1, 2 which is quoted by Matt 4:14 as applying to Jesus.
- Isa 9:7 is alluded to by Luke 1:32, 33, Rom 1:3, John 1:49, Matt 27:37, Heb 1:8, 9 as applying to Jesus as king of His spiritual kingdom of heaven, and thus Isa 9:7 is messianic.

Thus, Jesus achieved what this passage predicts.  Jesus conquered the burden of sin, was the great light (John 1:4) and increased Israel to include the children of promise (Gal 3:25-28, Rom 9:6-8).